# Convert IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, string>> to List<Dictionary<int, string>>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

```
var a = GetIEnumerableDictionary();
```

`a` is `IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, string>>`. 
How do I convert a to `List<Dictionary<int, string>>` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a.ToList()` should do the trick.

The `ToList()` extension method lives  in the `System.Linq` namespace.  If Linq is not available, the `List<T>` constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter, as Jalal has already answered on this page.

Comment: Assuming the OP has Linq at his disposable

Comment: Yeah! I've forgot to use namespace System.Linq!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the List `IEnumerable<T>` constructor, so:

```
List<Dictionary<int, string>> myList = new List<Dictionary<int, string>>(a);
```